# Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} x^n d\alpha(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis

For $\alpha$ of bounded variation on $[0,1]$.  Find

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} x^n d\alpha(x)$$

## My attempt:

i take $ \alpha  = p-q $,where $ p$ and $ q$ are monotonically  increasing on $[0,1] $. for $ \epsilon  \in (0,1) $, we have

$0\le \int_{0}^{\epsilon}x^ndp(x) \le \epsilon^n(p(\epsilon) - p(0))\rightarrow 0$ if $n$  tend to $\infty$

After that  i can not  able proceeded further

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: First fix $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, so that the integral from $1-\epsilon$ to $1$ is smaller than some (small) $\delta$ independent of $n$.

Comment: We can also apply the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 x^n \, \mathrm{d} \alpha(x) =  \mu_{\alpha}(\{1\})$, where $\mu$ is the induced measure.